# OleDbDataReader returns empty value

Tags: c#, sql

I have a couple of days to come up with a solution to my problem and I can not. When running the following code:

```
OleDbConnection MyconnectionBDD = null;
MyconnectionBDD = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + bdd.Text);
//MyconnectionBDD = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + bdd.Text);

MyconnectionBDD.Open();
OleDbCommand cmdBDD = MyconnectionBDD.CreateCommand();
OleDbDataReader dbReaderBDD = null;
string queryBDD;

queryBDD = "SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) AS CodEmp FROM Clientes WHERE Clientes.Codigo LIKE '" + int.Parse(dbReaderExcel.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(3, 2)) + "*'";
//queryBDD = "SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) FROM Clientes WHERE Codigo LIKE '17*'";
cmdBDD.CommandText = queryBDD;
cmdBDD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

dbReaderBDD = cmdBDD.ExecuteReader();

if (dbReaderBDD.HasRows)
{

    dbReaderBDD.Read();
    //string codEmp = dbReaderBDD.GetString(0); //GetValue(0).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(dbReaderBDD["CodEmp"].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString()); //GetInt64(0).ToString());
    //if (dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString() != "")
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString()))

        if (dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString().Length == 6)

            last_codigoCli = int.Parse(dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(1, 5));

        else

            last_codigoCli = int.Parse(dbReaderBDD.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(2, 5));

    last_codigoCli_Revisado = last_codigoCli;
}

dbReaderBDD.Close();
```

It returned an empty value, but if I run the query in Access it return a correct value:

```
SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) AS CodEmp FROM Clientes WHERE Clientes.Codigo LIKE '17*'
```

Please can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Ensure your `if` statement have curly braces around them to ensure the logic does exactly what you expect it to.

Comment: i think the value of `dbReaderExcel.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(3, 2)` is not 17 please check debug and see the exact value.

Comment: Hello Sudhakar. As You see in the code, if uncommented this line: 
//queryBDD = "SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) FROM Clientes WHERE Codigo LIKE '17*'";
the result is still empty. If I change the query to this: queryBDD = "SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) FROM Clientes";
 
if it works properly. Thanks

Comment: Hello Rob. I think the sentence is well written

Comment: The Codigo column contains the following data: Codigo
100
223
1300001
1300002
1300004
1300005
1300007
1300008
1300009
1300010
1700001
1700002
1700003
1700004
1700005
1700058
1700059
1700060
1700061
1700062
1700063
1700064
1700065
1700066
1700067
1700068

I need to stay with the maximum value depending on the first two issues. The first two numbers indicate the company. That is, if the first two numbers is 13 the query must return 1300010 and if the first two digits are 17, the query must return 1700068. thanks

Comment: Hello Sudhakar. Sorry, according to the comments I have written above would be: dbReaderExcel.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(0, 2) but still returns empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the query would be:

queryBDD = "SELECT MAX(Clientes.Codigo) AS CodEmp FROM Clientes WHERE Clientes.Codigo LIKE '" + int.Parse(dbReaderExcel.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(3, 2)) + "**%**'";

As the * is the wildcard in Access, I thought that the query had to put a * but was %

Thanks